# Getting something close to the convex full of SDFs using CSG operations

Tags: raytracing, glsl, mathematics, computational-geometry, signed-distance-field

Inigo Quilez has an [explanation](https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions/) of smooth operations to join sdfs.

I am trying to get something close to the convex hull of multiple sdfs. For starters let;s consider a simple case of 3 cubes int eh following configuration:

[image]

The convex hull would be a very, very similar shape, with the exception that the region inside the l shape would be a diagonal slope.

I tried using smooth joining operations with a high weight, but I get this

[image]

The area I expected to be filled is indeed filled, but everything else bloated up. I am trying to come up with a mathematical formula to test if a point would be inside the convex hull.

Comment: Here's a counterexample: take 2 spheres pretty close to infinitely far away. Then the cylinder between those is part of the convex hull. The CSG operations on the other hand will not reproduce it.

Comment: wdym? On that specific example you can use extrusion to get the cylinder.

Comment: The point was that smooth join will not work even for very simple cases.

Comment: I understand, I am asking if there is a way to get something close to the convex hull, even if it only works when the shapes are within a certain distance or something along those lines.